# How to add existing ssh key to project's deploy key in gitlab

Tags: git, bash, ssh, gitlab

I'm using gitlab.com, and I'm not that used to with SSH Keys. BTW I've managed to create a SSH Key in my Windows 8 PC using cmd and Git bash. And I've managed to add that to my gitlab user account.

Now in my project "Deploy Keys" I'm seeing:
[image: Deploy Keys - gitlab.com]

If I try to paste the same key here too, it's not adding because it's already taken.

The question can be answered by either of the following two:

- How can I add the existing one then? or,
- How can I make my SSH key active for my project, so that I can push into private repo of gitlab without username and password prompt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have one key both standard and "read-only". It does not make any sense.

If you want to "push into private repo of gitlab without username and password prompt". Just add the key as normal SSH-Key and you are good:

```
Profile Settings -> SSH keys
```

is the correct place where you should add your keys for read/write access.

Deploy keys are for read-only access!

---

**Edit from comments:** Also you need to change protocol, if you still use `https`. Change in `.git/config` in option `url` beginning from `https://gitlab.com/` to `git@gitlab.com:`

Comment: I's pushing a repo previously, so I've a remote set already. I've added my SSH Keys to gitlab.com, but still it's prompting me for the username and password. ([Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/av4qsc))

Comment: If you want to use keys, you need to use `ssh` protocol and not `https`: Change the `url` in `.git/config` from `https://gitlab.com...` to `git@gitlab.com...`

Comment: The replacement would be: from `https://gitlab.com/` to `git@gitlab.com:`. Thanks for the awesome to-the-point answer. Opened a new door to me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: thanks @Jakuje you saved my life with the comment about the URL :)